# Django + MQTT how to make request and wait for response in view

Tags: python-3.x, django, mqtt

I am writing a django application and I need a way how to ask for data on MQTT and wait for response (or timeout).

Something like this in view:

```py
mqtt.subscribe('response/topic')

mqtt.publish('request/topic', '{my json request message}')
for m in mqtt.on_message():
   if m.payload == '......'
       # OK I have response, render data from response to page, ...

# timeout could be implemented by raising exception in on_message()
```

How can i integrate paho mqtt? Or is there any other way? I need to wait for response on several places in views, one global `on_message` callback is not really useful.

Where should I put `mqtt.loop_forever()` in django?

Thank you

**EDIT:** my first solution is this:

```py
import queue
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def mqtt_request(req_topic, resp_topic, payload, timeout=2.0):
    q = queue.Queue()
    def on_message(client, userdata, message):
        q.put(message)

    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        c.subscribe(resp_topic)

    def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
        c.publish(req_topic, payload=payload, qos=0, retain=False)

    c = mqtt.Client()
    c.on_message = on_message
    c.on_connect = on_connect
    c.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
    c.connect_async('127.0.0.1')
    c.loop_start()

    m = None

    # FIXME: it seems that there is some delay between on_message and return
    # of the message...

    try:
        m = q.get(timeout=timeout)
    except queue.Empty:
        pass

    c.loop_stop()
    return m
```

usage in view:

```py
r = mqtt_request('test', 'test2', 'Ahoj')
if r:
    print(r.payload)
```

Comment: MQTT is not  a request/response protocol. you need to change your view of the problem, think about things in an asynchronous manner e.g. keeping a state machine.

Comment: @hardillb MQTT is much more than request/response protocol, but why it could not be used for request/response ?

Comment: MQTT is inherently asynchronous, while you can send request/response messages you have approach the problem with that in mind. Trying to implement hard blocking for a response is the wrong way to think about this.